# centralManagerDidUpdateState returns power off iOS 11-Beta 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I'm working with `CoreBluetooth` and I'm using `CBCentralManager` and its delegates. But the problem is that when I run my code in `iOS 11-Beta 4` I get power off state in delegate `- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central` while bluetooth is ON.

When I turn bluetooth off and then turn it back to on, it returns power on. Also it is working fine in iOS 10 and 9. The peripheral is working fine too and it is discoverable using LightBlue application in iOS 11-Beta 4. I'm not sure why it's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like bug there, check the bug report here:

https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=33728133

Also stated that:

> iOS 11 is in general going to be less forgiving for apps which don't
>   hold a proper reference to CB objects even if the problem described
>   here becomes less severe. So, the best is to manage object life cycles
>   properly.

Also, advised to update and check with Beta 5.

Check the complete thread here for more info:

[iOS 11 - CoreBluetooth Broken If Using State Presevation and Peripheral Not Cancelled Properly](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84098)

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes it seems the problem was because of iOS bug. it is fixed now in iOS 11 - Beta 5

Comment: Great...HTH@HassanShahbazi